# Wine command not found after building it

Tags: software-installation, wine, compiling

I've just installed Wine 3.5 which released recently, configured the CMake files, compiled it, and installed. Commands used were:

```
cd Desktop/wine-3.5
./configure --enable-win64 --without-freetype
make
sudo make install
```

However, when I try to run Wine, it says it couldn't be found. I looked into `/usr/bin` and it wasn't there. I tried installing it again, and it didn't work. Any thoughts in the matter?

Comment: Did you look in `/usr/local/bin`?

Comment: Ah. Seems like wine alone is the 32 bit application. I have to type wine64. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `wine` is for 32-bit prefixes/applications and `wine64` is for 64-bit prefixes/applications. Since the compatibility rate is higher on 32-bit applications, I would recommend that you also build `wine`.

Comment: @Ace It seems you found the answer--that you only compiled the 64-bit version of Wine, and the command for that is `wine64`. So I recommend [posting your own answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer).